# Wordpress custom taxonomy with custom fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy, organization

We are building a book shop with WP and Woocommerce, have some doubts with the organization of post-types and taxonomies.

Because the Woocommerce platform doesn't come with built-in fields like "author", or "manufacturer", "brand", we thought that it could be achieved with custom taxonomies.

First of all, we created some books, in Woocommerce as "products". Then created the custom taxonomy called "Autores", similar to "Authors", but nothing to do, we don't want it to be connected any way...  The "Autores" taxonomy we decided to make it hierarchical.

In this custom taxonomy, added the first 3 items, 3 books authors, each of them are assigned to a different book inside product edit pages.

Now, in the WP menus, we can link every one of the book authors, as a category archive. This is useful, because we could add custom fields to the taxonomy itself, like "authour website", "author picture", "author bio", etc.   The goal with this is to have a page for each author, in which we display the name, description, custom fields, and then below the products assigned to that author.

We are considering to do this with the help of this tutorial: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-additional-custom-meta-fields-to-custom-taxonomies/

The second question is related to this custom taxonomy too... How could we have a page to be an index with the list of authors, listed alphabetically, with some of their custom fields like "author picture" and their product count?

Have worked with custom post types before, in other projects, but not with Woocommerce involved.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to checkout the Toolset plugins.

http://wp-types.com/learn/create-an-ecommerce-wordpress-site/create-custom-fields-and-taxonomies/